# If Else: String Equality (Java)

Tags: string, if-statement, equality

Lab Description : Compare two strings to see if each of the two strings contains the same letters in the
same order.

This is what I have so far far:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class StringEquality
{
   private String wordOne, wordTwo;

   public StringEquality()
   {
   }

   public StringEquality(String one, String two)
   {
      setWords (wordOne, wordTwo);
   }

   public void setWords(String one, String two)
   {
      wordOne = one;
      wordTwo = two;
   }

   public boolean checkEquality()
   {
      if (wordOne == wordTwo)
      return true;
      else
      return false;
   }

  public String toString()
  {
    String output = "";
    if (checkEquality())
    output += wordOne + " does not have the same letters as " + wordTwo;
    else
    output += wordOne + " does have the same letters as " + wordTwo;
    return output;
  }
}
```

My runner looks like this:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class StringEqualityRunner
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    StringEquality test = new StringEquality();

    test.setWords(hello, goodbye);
    out.println(test);


}
}
```

Everything is compiling except for the runner. It keeps saying that hello and goodbye aren't variables. How can I fix this so that the program does not read hello and goodbye as variables, but as Strings?

Comment: Apart from what is in the answers, you don't compare string with `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: Does the description suggest to be able to detect that the two strings contain the same sequence of characters? In that case the solution would be more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code is with `checkEquality()`, you are comparing the string's position in memory when you use `==` use `.equals()` to check the string

```
public boolean checkEquality()
{ 
  if (wordOne == wordTwo) //use wordOne.equals(wordTwo) here
     return true;
  else
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote strings otherwise they are treated as variables.

```
"hello"
"goodbye"
```

so this would work better.

```
test.setWords("hello", "goodbye");
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose them in double-quotes.